# What is the equivalent to “MarketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier" for windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

In Windows Phone 8.0 i used this to open an app on the store

```
    MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
    marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier = "**************";
```

This Class does not exists in WP 8.1 how can i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the new launchers.

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-windows-store:navigate?appid=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"));
```